# Debugging IPhone with GDB

Tags: iphone, gdb

I've an IPhone (iOS 4.2.1). I'd like to debug apps on it, with gdb. I understand that's easy (?) with XCode, when being a registered developer. I'm not a registered dev., and I don't want to be one.
To be more specific, I want to be able to attach to safari with gdb and debug it, by any means (jailbreak is ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install gdb on a jailbroken iPhone using Cydia or via `apt-get install gdb` from shell if you already have apt packages installed.

Then run gdb on device, from shell by ssh... attach / start process... gdb classic use.

I guess it is possible to run remotely gdb from a computer, but never tried outside Xcode.

As a side note, when remoting you device, for best use, do it through USB and not wifi.
You can do this on linux/OSX using [usbmuxd](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SSH_Over_USB). On PC i guess iTunnel or something like.

And as a second side note, Years ago I was developing without being "a registered developer", with a jailbroken iPhone it is not hard to *"bypass"* Apple validations and to Debug directly from Xcode...

Comment: Can you please elabrote on how you debugged directly from Xcode?

Comment: It was a long time ago... I guess i was using `gdbserver`: http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb-5.1.1/html_node/gdb_130.html